# Why my NgMessages form validation is not behaving like appropriately?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a code which uses Angular JS form validation.

There are two forms, 
The first uses form validation

and the second use ng-messages,

The problem is, the second form doesn't seems to work as first one.

In the first form, 3 text fields,

end field has required.

So once I load the page and try to submit the form without filling it,
the error messages appear across the respective fields.

Now if the text field is not empty but has some number validation, 
and if I enter text, that only number validation message is shown.

But the same kind for above mentioned validation behavior I am not able to implement in my second form using ng-Messages.

The code is as below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Validator Examples</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/rahul/Installers/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/rahul/Installers/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/rahul/Installers/Bootstrapv3.0.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/rahul/Installers/Bootstrapv3.0.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/rahul/Installers/Bootstrapv3.0.2/css/bootstrap-theme.css">


    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module("myApp",[]);
        angular.module("myApp").controller("myCtrl",myCtrl);
        function myCtrl(){
            var vm = this;
            vm.formOne = {}
            vm.formOne.name = "";
            vm.formOne.address = "";                
            vm.formOne.age = 0;

            vm.formTwo = {}
            vm.formTwo.name = "";
            vm.formTwo.address = "";                
            vm.formTwo.age = 0;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .form-error{
            color : red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>Validator Examples</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h5><b>ngForm Validator Examples</b></h5>
                </div>
                <form name="formOne" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name1" placeholder="Name" required ng-model="vm.formOne.name"
                         minlength="5" maxlength="10" />
                        <div ng-show="formOne.$submitted || formOne.name1.$touched">
                            <div ng-show="formOne.name1.$error.required" class="form-error">Name can't be empty</div>
                            <div ng-show="formOne.name1.$error.minlength" class="form-error">Name can't be less than 5</div>
                            <div ng-show="formOne.name1.$error.maxlength" class="form-error">Name can't be more than 10</div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" placeholder="Address" ng-model="vm.formOne.address"
                         required />
                        <div ng-show="formOne.$submitted || formOne.address1.$touched">
                            <div ng-show="formOne.address1.$error.required" class="form-error">Address can't be empty</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="age1" placeholder="Age" ng-model="vm.formOne.age"
                         required number/>
                        <div ng-show="formOne.$submitted || formOne.age1.$touched">
                            <div ng-show="formOne.age1.$error.required" class="form-error">Age can't be empty</div>
                            <div ng-show="formOne.age1.$error.number" class="form-error">Age should be numeric</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h5><b>ngForm ngMessages Validator Examples</b></h5>
                </div>
                <form name="formTwo" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name1" placeholder="Name"
                        ng-model="vm.formTwo.name" required ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" />
                        <div ng-messages="formTwo.name1.$error" 
                        ng-show="formTwo.$submitted || formTwo.name1.$touched" class="form-error" role="alert">
                            <div ng-message="required">Name can't be empty</div>
                            <div ng-message="minlength">Name can't be less than 5</div>
                            <div ng-message="maxlength">Name can't be more than 10</div>                
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" placeholder="Address" ng-model="vm.formTwo.address"
                         required  />
                        <div ng-messages="formTwo.address1.$error"
                         ng-show="formTwo.$submitted || formTwo.address1.$touched" class="form-error">
                            <div ng-message="required">Name can't be empty</div>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="age1" placeholder="Age" ng-model="vm.formTwo.age"
                         required number />
                        <div ng-messages="formTwo.age1.$error" ng-show="formTwo.$submitted || formTwo.age1.$touched"
                          class="form-error">
                            <div ng-message="required">Age can't be empty</div>
                            <div ng-message="number">Age should be numeric</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Let me show you the comparison,

in form one the first files validation is like

```
<form name="formOne" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name1" placeholder="Name" required ng-model="vm.formOne.name"
                         minlength="5" maxlength="10" />
                        <div ng-show="formOne.$submitted || formOne.name1.$touched">
                            <div ng-show="formOne.name1.$error.required" class="form-error">Name can't be empty</div>
                            <div ng-show="formOne.name1.$error.minlength" class="form-error">Name can't be less than 5</div>
                            <div ng-show="formOne.name1.$error.maxlength" class="form-error">Name can't be more than 10</div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
```

And in the form two, the validation is like

```
<form name="formTwo" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name1" placeholder="Name"
                        ng-model="vm.formTwo.name" required ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" />
                        <div ng-messages="formTwo.name1.$error" 
                        ng-show="formTwo.$submitted || formTwo.name1.$touched" class="form-error" role="alert">
                            <div ng-message="required">Name can't be empty</div>
                            <div ng-message="minlength">Name can't be less than 5</div>
                            <div ng-message="maxlength">Name can't be more than 10</div>                
                        </div>
```

In form one, I am able to see only those messages which are invalid,

But in form two I see all the error messages in that field.

You can also see my working code on this like,

[FormValidation](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/L8Lhtswn/)

Please let me know, were I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- make sure you have added *angular-message.js* file in `<script>`
- than Inject `ngMessages` in module like below

`angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);`

- Write controller alias with `form="vm.formTwo"` and `ng-messages="vm.formTwo....`

here is the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/L8Lhtswn/2/)